# Creating File Geodatabase from KML using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, kml, file-geodatabase

Is there a way to create a FileGDB from a KML?

I have tried with QGIS 2.18.7 but cannot figure out a way.

Comment: Both File Geodatabase and KML are container classes. You might have more success if you research how to populate an FGDB *table* from a combination of KML Placemarks with same topology class geometry objects and ExtendedData.

Comment: What precisely did you try in QGIS?